# Error 500 - Angularjs with DNN - Christoc.Module ng-include

Tags: angularjs, dotnetnuke

I have an application that I build using VB.NET and angularJS in DNN with the Christoc.Module module.  There seems to be 2 issues.  When I build my project and refresh the page on my site, I will receive an error 500.  The same result happens on the site unexpectedly after being idle for about 30 minutes. I have tried to change settings on the website web.config to see if it was a session expiry timeout, but that doesn't seem to be the case since all pages that where access before the error are fine, and can access server functions.

I was wondering if anyone has ever seen something similar.

I use ng-include to show the current "active page". I have tried using the AngularJS $route and the same behaviour occured.

`<div class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="path in PathLinks| filter:{'path_name':variable}:true" ng-include="'/DesktopModules/module/path/' + path.path_name + '.aspx></div>`

[CLick here for image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMoRf.png)

Comment: I'm not sure, it reminds me problem I had with ASP.net and AngularJS, I think it have something to do with <base href="/"> missing in page <head>. Check that link: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thank you for commenting!  I have added a base in the page <head> of my application.  Unfortunately, I have tested the application for a few hours and the same issue happens.  It's a really strange one.  If you have any other suggestions, I would love the help.  Cheers.

Comment: In IIS check the site to see if the DesktopModules directory, or any sub directories, keep getting turned into a virtual directory

Comment: @ChristianBeaudry can you post a screenshot of the error or the console error stack?

Comment: @ChrisHammond Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, IIS has been checked - This isn't the case for this issue.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil - I have added a link to the image of the error found in the console.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply recreating the whole module with a newer version of the visual Studio DotNetNuke Compiled Module.  The original module was created using an older version of that extension.  This seemed to have completely fixed the issue for me.